# Unable to select the value automatically in drop down for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I've the html as scripted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <select id="drop_down_id">
          <option value="1">Volvo</option>
          <option value="2">Saab</option>
          <option value="3">Opel</option>
          <option value="4">Audi</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

For this html, i'm selecting the option dynamically by using below code

```
var theText = "Saab";
$("#drop_down_id option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected').change();//If we not using change() also it'll work
```

at first time it's working fine but when i'm using it for second time with the same option it's not selecting the option

**Explanation**

Let assume, for first time I've selected the value `Saab` then I've selected `Volvo` and `Audi`. If tried again to select `Saab` or `Volvo` or `Audi` it's not selecting the option. Any one know how to achieve it in `jQuery` or `JavaScript`

Comment: It's working fine. I can select any option anytime.

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using `chrome`

Comment: Thank you Usman Rana. Vineesh answer was working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you select one option, it will add `selected` attribute to that option. You are not removing the existing selected options So before you try selecting again you should remove the selected attribute from existing options

https://jsfiddle.net/9v8way30/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var theText = "Audi";
  $("#drop_down_id option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected').change();
   theText = "Saab";
  $("#drop_down_id option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected').change();
  $('#drop_down_id option').removeAttr('selected');
    theText = "Audi";
  $("#drop_down_id option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected').change();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's working but i'm executing `$('#drop_down_id option').removeAttr('selected');` before my code on every time

Answer (score 0):

```
The above code adds the 'selected' attribute for each option which you are changing dynamically. Initially you need to remove the existing selected attribute from options

$("#drop_down_id").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
    $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```